# Error Building & Installing Apache Atlas

Tags: java, maven, java-9, apache-atlas

I was trying to setup apache atlas using [this link](http://atlas.apache.org/InstallationSteps.html).

While running this:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m" && mvn clean install
```

I'm getting the following build failure:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 04:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-18T15:49:16+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 80M/268M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project atlas-hbase-client-shaded:
        Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.atlas:atlas-hbase-client-shaded:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:
        Could not find artifact jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.7 at specified path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/../lib/tools.jar
```

Please let me know how to fix this.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Please let me know if anything else is required.

Answer (score 1):

Found this below on http://hadoopinrealworld.com/missing-artifact-jdk-tools-jar/
It is very easy to solve the problem. Simply add the below dependency to your pom.xml.

```
<groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
<version>1.7.0_05</version>
<scope>system</scope>
<systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is mostly because of the codeApache Atlas should be built by JDK instead of the JRE. I got the same error, so I removed the JRE and installed the one with JDK and I went past that error.